# Is there a way to overload the index assignment operator?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I can overload the `[]` operator with `Index` to return a ref, but I don't know if I have an overloaded operator to assign to the object.

This is what I want to do:

```
point[0] = 9.9;
```

This is what I can do so far (get a value):

```
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    e: [f32; 3],
}

impl Index<usize> for Vec3 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a f32 {
        &self.e[i]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let point = Vec3 { e: [0.0, 1.0, 3.0] };
    let z = point[2];
    println!("{}", z);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html), which says this in its documentation:

> If a mutable value is requested, [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) is used instead.

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    e: [f32; 3],
}

impl Index<usize> for Vec3 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a f32 {
        &self.e[i]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<usize> for Vec3 {
    fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, i: usize) -> &'a mut f32 {
        &mut self.e[i]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut point = Vec3 { e: [0.0, 1.0, 3.0] };
    point[0] = 99.9;
}
```

See also:

- [Update value in mutable HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30414424/155423) (why you cannot *create* a new value using the `IndexMut` trait)

Comment: @JohnEstess that's why I linked to the extra question; it doesn't really have to do with `HashMap` (as I attempted to indicate in the parenthetical). Right now, there's no way to say `foo[index_not_in_collection] = new_value`. You can only do `foo[index_in_collection] = replacement_value`. Thus `IndexMut` returns a mutable reference that you then can use or replace, but it must already exist.

Comment: @JohnEstess *the rather obtuse example* — Rust strives for good documentation. I'm sure that if you filed an issue explaining why the example threw you, someone would appreciate the feedback and might adjust the example accordingly.

Comment: @Shepmaster not really true, you could add a new value, just modify the `index_mut` implementation to increase the size of the vector before returning.

Comment: @edulix not really. `DerefMut` needs to return a `&mut T`, and all references must be valid otherwise you create undefined behavior. You could increase the size of the vector, but you wouldn't have a valid value to store in that vector before returning a reference to it. Try implementing your suggestion to see the problem first-hand. ^_^