# Rust: cannot use HashMap::<Point,bool>

Tags: indexing, rust, hashmap

I have a struct-tuple named Point. It is a 2D cartesian coordinates. I need to use a point as a key in a hashmap but the compiler refuses. How do I approach this?

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Point(i16, i16);

const ROOT: Point = Point(0,0);

let mut visited = std::collections::HashMap::<Point,bool>::new();
visited[&ROOT] = true;
```

Compiler error is following:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in an index of `std::collections::HashMap<Point, bool>`
   --> src/main.rs:124:3
    |
124 |         visited[&ROOT] = true;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
    |
    = help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<Point, bool>`
```

Comment: you could read the documentation of hashmap :p https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update a value in a mutable HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414424/how-can-i-update-a-value-in-a-mutable-hashmap)

Comment: @Stargateur I would say that this is not a good dup, the current question is about adding a value to a map, while your linked question is about updating a value already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap` does not implement `IndexMut`. Mutation of entries works through `get_mut()` with borrowed keys or through the `entry()` API with owned keys.

In your case, `get_mut()` will return `None` since you have not inserted anything into your map. `visited.insert(ROOT, true)` will do that for you.