# How to transform HashMap value in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a HashMap with key = id, value = Status;
Now I want to update the status, but I have to remove and insert, because the new status is created from the old status. Is there any way to update without remove and insert?

```rust
enum Status {
    InCompleted(HashSet<WorkerId>),
    Working(WorkerId, HashSet<WorkerId>),
    Completed,
}
impl Status {
    fn to_working(self, worker_id: WorkerId) -> Self {
        match self {
            Self::InCompleted(w) => Self::Working(worker_id, w),
            _ => self,
        }
    }
// remove and insert new
let old_status = h.remove(&id).unwrap();
h.insert(id, old_status.to_working(cur_worker));
```

Comment: If you change the `Value` type of the map to `Option<Status>`, that would be easy. If not, think of what would happen if your `to_working()` panics, what would the state of the map be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update a value in a mutable HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414424/how-can-i-update-a-value-in-a-mutable-hashmap)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `entry` method for `HashMap`, and its [`and_modify`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.and_modify) method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.and_modify.

You can have something like:

```rust
h.entry(&id).and_modify(|status| 
    *status = status.to_working(cur_worker)
);
```

Comment: The OP needs ownership of the value.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman True. This only works if the `to_working` method can be modified to take `&mut self`.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing that is exactly the same, unfortunately, but you can avoid looking up the value twice by replacing with the default, then inserting the new value. Note that it requires `T: Default`. If it is not, use a sensible default value (it'll stay there if the transformation will panic)

```rust
let status = h.get_mut(&id).unwrap();
let old_status = std::mem::take(status);
*status = old_status.to_working(cur_worker);
```

You can use a crate like [replace_with](https://lib.rs/crates/replace_with):

```rust
replace_with::replace_with_or_default(
    h.get_mut(&id).unwrap(),
    |old_status| old_status.to_working(cur_worker),
);
```